# How to extract bitmap from .ico

Tags: actionscript, bitmap, icons, png

using actionscript 3, how can I extract the bitmap from a .ico file? ( preferably in .png format )

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested this library but it seems to do what you are attempting:

http://www.libspark.org/svn/as3/ICODecoder/src/com/voidelement/images/ico/

Here is a link to a blog post demonstrating implementation:

http://ntt.cc/2008/10/02/using-icodecoder-class-to-read-ico-file-and-display-it-as-bitmap-in-actionscript.html

Comment: Both links no longer work.